# How to visible/hide password in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have created a login screen for my app but in password field I want a functionality like when I type password its been in * format and in right side a icon on when user click on it, password will be visible, I created a code for it but when I click on password field that icon getting invisible and when password field loose focus that icon appearing again, then how to always show that icon even password field is in focus?
I have provided a snapshot to easily understand the problem.

[image]

[image]

Here are my login screen code....

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/screens/home_screen/Home.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/screens/home_screen/passwords/PasswordsNavigation.dart';
import 'package:secret_keeper/screens/signup_page/SignupPage.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  String _emailID, _password = "",_email = "abc@gmail.com", _pass = "Try.t.r.y@1";
  bool _obscureText = true;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  void _toggle(){
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  void validateLogin(){
    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      if(_emailID == _email && _password == _pass){
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
      }
    }
  }

  Widget emailInput(){
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email ID",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.red,
            )
        ),
      ),
      validator: (email) {
        if (email.isEmpty)
          return 'Please Enter email ID';
        else if (!EmailValidator.validate(email))
          return 'Enter valid email address';
        else
          return null;
      },
      onSaved: (email)=> _emailID = email,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    );
  }

  Widget passInput(){
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,color: Colors.grey.shade400),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        ),
        suffixIcon: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            _obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
          ),
          onPressed: _toggle,
        ),
      ),
      validator: (password){
        Pattern pattern =
            r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
        RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
        if (password.isEmpty){
          return 'Please Enter Password';
        }else if (!regex.hasMatch(password))
          return 'Enter valid password';
        else
          return null;
      },
      onSaved: (password)=> _password = password,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      obscureText: _obscureText,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16,right: 16),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height: 50,),
                    Text("Welcome,",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                    SizedBox(height: 6,),
                    Text("Sign in to continue!",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.grey.shade400),),
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    emailInput(),
                    SizedBox(height: 16,),
                    passInput(),
                    SizedBox(height: 12,),
                    Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                      child: Text("Forgot Password ?",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30,),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: validateLogin,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        child: Ink(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            gradient: LinearGradient(
                              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              end: Alignment.centerRight,
                              colors: [
                                Color(0xffff5f6d),
                                Color(0xffff5f6d),
                                Color(0xffffc371),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: double.infinity,minHeight: 50),
                            child: Text("Login",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                          ),
                        ),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16,),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.indigo.shade50,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 18,width: 18,),
                            SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text("Connect with Facebook",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16,),
                    Container(
                      height: 50,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        color: Colors.indigo.shade50,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset("assets/images/facebook.png",height: 18,width: 18,),
                            SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text("Connect with Facebook",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.indigo,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Don't have an account?",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      SizedBox(width: 5,),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                            return SignupPage();
                          }));
                        },
                        child: Text("Sign up",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.red),),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the suffix icon is visible but when i click on TextFormField then the icon color is changing to white so simply in icon field i added a color property and give a black color to icon so even textfield is in focus its color remain black.

Answer (score 3):

Full Example.main login here is:

1. take a boolean param for detecting if text is obscure or not
2. change suffix icon based on that boolean value
3. change the boolean value on suffix item click

below i gave a full example for the task.

```
bool _passwordInVisible = true; //a boolean value

TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
return TextFormField(
  obscureText: _passwordInVisible,
  onSaved: (newValue) => registerRequestModel.password = newValue,
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (value.isNotEmpty) {
      removeError(error: kPassNullError);
    } else if (value.length >= 8) {
      removeError(error: kShortPassError);
    }
    return null;
  },
  validator: (value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      addError(error: kPassNullError);
      return "";
    } else if (value.length < 8) {
      addError(error: kShortPassError);
      return "";
    }
    return null;
  },
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: "Password",
    hintText: "Enter your password",
    contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 15.0),
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        _passwordInVisible ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility, //change icon based on boolean value
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark, 
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _passwordInVisible = !_passwordInVisible; //change boolean value
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: It's better to add some description.

Comment: Awesome and to the point. Thanks!

Comment: Explanation: 1) InputDecoration has a property called suffixIcon wherein we can provide any widget that will be visible to the end of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Here two scenarios come

1. If you want your suffix icon color constant like always grey, you can give color property of icon, like :

> button for password show hide

```
var passShowButton = GestureDetector(
      onLongPressEnd: outContact,
      onTapDown: inContact, //call this method when incontact
      onTapUp:
          outContact, //call this method when contact with screen is removed
      child: Icon(
        getXHelper.isEmailPasswordUpdate.isTrue
            ? AppIcons.hidePassword
            : AppIcons.hidePassword,
        size: 18,
        color:Colors.grey
      ),
    );
```

> TextField

```
TextField(
    obscureText: getXHelper.isPassInvisible  ,
    autocorrect: false,
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabled: true,
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      isDense: true,
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 18, minHeight: 18),
      hintText: "Password",
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, right: 12, bottom: 0),
        child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 18, color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      suffixIcon: passShowButton,
    ),
    cursorColor: Colors.black,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontFamily: AppFontFamily.fontFamily),
  )
```

2. If you want your suffix icon color of your app-Primary Color, will change color when textfield focus, like :

> Password show hide button

```
var passShowButton = GestureDetector(
          onLongPressEnd: outContact,
          onTapDown: inContact, //call this method when incontact
          onTapUp:
              outContact, //call this method when contact with screen is removed
          child: Icon(
            getXHelper.isEmailPasswordUpdate.isTrue
                ? AppIcons.hidePassword
                : AppIcons.hidePassword,
            size: 18,
          ),
        );

TextField(
    obscureText: getXHelper.isPassInvisible  ,
    autocorrect: false,
    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabled: true,
      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      border: UnderlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.primary)),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      filled: true,
      isDense: true,
      prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 18, minHeight: 18),
      hintText: "Password",
      prefixIcon: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, right: 12, bottom: 0),
        child: Icon(Icons.lock, size: 18),
      ),
      suffixIcon: passShowButton,
    ),
    cursorColor: Colors.black,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black, fontFamily: AppFontFamily.fontFamily),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put text field and icon button in a stack
replace this code with your password textfield.
you can change icon button position to what you want.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Password",
            labelStyle:
                TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              ),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.red,
                )),
          ),
          validator: (password) {
            Pattern pattern =
                r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[!@#\$&*~]).{8,}$';
            RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
            if (password.isEmpty) {
              return 'Please Enter Password';
            } else if (!regex.hasMatch(password))
              return 'Enter valid password';
            else
              return null;
          },
          onSaved: (password) => _password = password,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          obscureText: _obscureText,
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 2,
          right: 10,
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                _obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                });
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Although this seems like a good solution at first, I would not recommend this approach over the suffixIcon already provided. This solution has an issue when the hint animates to the top of the TextField which in turn causes the height of the widget to change which in turn causes the icon to not be in the center of the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and run your code and it works just fine. The icon was visible when the password field had focus. You should maybe check your flutter version or it might probably be your emulator device. 
`flutter --version` 
Flutter 1.22.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git 
Framework • revision 8874f21e79 (2 weeks ago) • 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700 
Engine • revision a1440ca392 
Tools • Dart 2.10.3 
[image: I have focus and it works]

Comment: I am also using same version of flutter 'Flutter 1.22.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8874f21e79 (2 weeks ago) • 2020-10-29 14:14:35 -0700
Engine • revision a1440ca392
Tools • Dart 2.10.3
'